# C言語のポインターで詰まっている。

Tags: c

下記でコンパイルエラーになる。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *buf="<title>sample</title>";
    char work[256];
    char *p;

    char *out=work;
    char *in=buf;

    in=strstr(in,"<");
    while(strcmp((*p=(*out++ = *in++)),"sample") != 0);
    printf("%c",p);

    //while(strcmp((*out++=*in++),">") != 0);
    *out='\0';
    printf("%s\n",out);
    return 0;
}
```

下記のエラーが出る。

```
01.c: In function 'main':
01.c:14:2: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  while(strcmp((*p=(*out++ = *in++)),"sample") != 0);
  ^
In file included from 01.c:3:0:
c:\mingw\include\string.h:43:37: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
 _CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strcmp (const char*, const char*)  __MINGW_ATTRIB_PURE;
                                     ^
```

済みません。間違いを指摘願います。
尚、出来ればコードでの回答をお願いします。
その方が理解が早いので。協力をお願いします。

Comment: ■タイトルにはご質問の内容をもう少し具体的に含めるようにしてください。似た文言で異なる質問内容を続けられるのは大きな混乱の元です。■質問内容についても、コードを掲載して『うまく動かない』と他人事のように書いた挙句に、「修正用のコードだけ示せ」では、「俺の代わりに俺の仕事をしろ、俺が何をやりたいかはうまく想像しろ」と言っているようなものです。もう少し「やりたいこと」「うまくいかない点」「特に聞きたいところ」などをご質問中にうまく説明するようにしてください。■さらに過去のご質問で一度も「承認」の操作をされていないようですが、あなたの問題の解決に直接結びついた回答には「承認」のチェックをするようにしてください。　以上はStackOverflowと言うサイトが多くの技術者にとって有用な(当然未来に検索などで訪れることになる方々も含んでいます)情報源となるよう積み上げられてきた仕組みの一部です。ご協力をお願いします。

Comment: 済みません。承認とはどう言う事を言うのでしょうか。操作が分かりません。

Comment: @yamada [「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をご覧下さい。

Comment: このコードの目的は`title`タグで囲まれたテキスト(`sample`)を`work`に取り出すことですか？ 問題点(1)として、`strcmp`は`'\0'`で終了している`char`の並びを比較文字列としますから部分文字列の一致を試すのには使えません。問題点(2)として、`*out='\0';
    printf("%s\n",out);` の部分で`out`はヌル文字を指していますから（取り出した文字列の）表示がされません。おそらく`work`を使って`printf("%s\n", work);`のようにすべきだと思います。

Comment: 難しくて、操作が分からない。色々と指摘を受けているが、では、私は何をすれば良いのか。私の今は、質問の内容が不適切に投稿をしているので一旦閉じて再度の質問を出したいが。そうすると、怒られる。どうすれば良いのか分からないために今は放置している。今回の私の質問は明らかに内容に問題が有るのは分かっているのですが。この様な場合の処理はどうすれば良いのか。システムとして見た場合は、非常に扱いにくいシステムに見えます。

Comment: @yamada 新たに質問するのではなく，この質問の内容を編集してコードの目的，すなわち，どういう入力に対してどういう処理をしたいかを追記すれば良いかと思います．現状このコードで何をしたいのかはyamadaさんしか知らない状態なので他の人間が質問の体裁を整える編集リクエストも投げられないという状況になってしまっています．

Comment: このサイトには[質問者が回答を締め切る機能はない](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2416/8000)ので、「一旦閉じて質問しなおす」ことに相当するのは**質問を削除して再投稿**することです。ただし[これを繰り返すと投稿が制限されてしまいます](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2428/8000)。より良い方法は、okdshinさんも書かれているように、**既存の質問を編集**して改善することです。質問文の下に[編集]というリンクがあり、そちらをクリックしていただくと質問文を修正することができます。/ その他にシステムやルールについてわからないことやご意見がありましたら、メタと呼ばれる運営掲示板のような場所( http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/ )がありますので、そちらにお寄せいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

落ち着いて警告とエラーを読んでみてください．
`strcmp`関数は第一引数に`char`ポインタ型を取りますが，`*p`は`char`型変数です．

また，次の行ですが

```
printf("%c",p);
```

`%c`はchar型変数を表示するためのものですが，`p`は`char`ポインタ型なので合っていません．ポインタの値を表示したいなら`%p`を，NULL終端文字列を表示したいなら`%s`を使いましょう．

`char`型と`char`ポインタ型を混同しているように見受けられます．両者の違いを確認してください．

Comment: *out++ = *in++の返す値と言うのは、ポインターで無いと言う事でしょうか。若しも、これがポインターでないとすると、これをポインターにキャストする事は出来るのでしょうか。printfの所は、”%c"については、*pにしますが。問題はそこではなくて、while文の中がどうなのかを知りたいです。。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: ポインタではないです．キャストはできますがやる意味はありません（おそらくyamadaさんのやりたいこともキャストではないと思われます）．while文の部分についてアドバイスしたいのはやまやまなんですが，まず何をするためのコードか明示してください．